# Matlab scripting, Customizing Figures

Tags: matlab

In Matlab scripting, how can I set two different Y-Axis for a single figure (one on the left and the other on the right side of the figure) ???

Answer (score 4):

from here : [mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/plotyy.html)

```
plotyy(X1,Y1,X2,Y2)
plotyy(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,function)
plotyy(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,'function1','function2')
```